# Trackpad gestures problems

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad, gestures, touchegg

I have a Clevo P150SM with a synaptics trackpad and I wish to have multi-touch gestures for expo, scale, show desktop, change view port, etc...

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 with mate as a desktop environment and have synclient.

I searched the web and found touchegg and I installed it from the repos and it did not work, then I tried to install it by the source and it did not work.

Touchegg runs on terminal and displays the information of the gestures but then if I make a gesture it does not do anything.

An example I created a gesture for "all" to make a mouse click (button 1) with 4 fingers I rebooted the PC logged in but it did nothing.

(I have the touchegg in the startup applications).

Does any one has touchegg working in ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problems, on a Dell XPS 12 9Q33 running Xubuntu 13.10

I installed touchegg using

```
$ sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

but nothing seemed to work in the program.

What was really odd was that when I tried to compile the touchegg gui from source:

https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce

it wouldn't work...gave me a weird make error, something to to tune of:
"Make: No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/mkspecs/de Make Stop"

Researching more, at least for, looks like it may be an upstream bug...because the system recognizes my touchscreen, the computer also thinks the touch pad is a normal touchpad, not a synaptics one

http://libcoding.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/issue-with-touchpad-in-ubuntu-13-10-in-xps-12/comment-page-1/#comment-22

Apparently the workaround is blacklisting the i2c_hid module , which the dude explains how to do

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change your touchpad configuration to use evdev driver and  restart X. Have a look at the [Touchegg Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/ConfigureDevices) how to do that.

After you've done that you have to create the gestures. Make sure you are applying your changes to the config file located in your home directory.

```
~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

If you don't have any file in this place copy the following file to the path above.

```
/usr/share/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

Comment: Yes I did that still not working

Comment: I edited my answer. Perhaps it helps you out now....